# How does Google Chrome recognize a login form?

Tags: html, google-chrome, authentication, passwords

I faced an issue recently where Google Chrome offers to save username and password for a login form, but took a different field value than the username-field to store as username.

Does anyone know which criteria are used by chrome to determine the username and password in a login form?

My guess (but cannot find documentation to proof it):

- take first text-field as username
- take first password field as password

Comment: This has some related information: http://superuser.com/questions/86282/chrome-auto-fill-username-passwords-is-inconsistant

Answer (score -2):

When a website developer creates a login form on their website, they usually add specific HTML tags to the form to identify it as a login form. When a user visits the website and clicks on the form, the browser recognizes the HTML tags and knows that the form is a login form. The browser may then offer to save the user's login information, so that the user doesn't have to enter it every time they visit the website.

Here is an example of a login form with HTML tags:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this example, the form tag specifies that this is a form, and the input tags with the type attribute set to "text" or "password" specify that this is a login form.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).